# HTML with separate stylesheet changes Webpage appearance

Tags: html, css

When the styles are in same HTML file, page is looking as expected. When the styles are split into separate CSS file with link in HTML file, page format is changed.

Can you please check what should be changed in split file to get same appearance. (Did not include image)

HTML code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Split Check</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="link.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="container1">
        <figure><img class="logo" src="image.jpg" alt="Alt"></figure>
        <div class="hdr_txt">FULL NAME
            <div class="c1_font">DESIGNATION</div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <hr class="line">
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
<style>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.container1 {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 80%;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    max-width: 20%;
    max-height: 5%;
}

.hdr_txt {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 60%;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    direction: rtl;
}

.c1_font {
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-family: Times;
    direction: rtl;
}

.line {
    width: 80%;
    height: 10%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #7d97ad;
}

</style>
```

All in one code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Split Check</title>
    <style>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.container1 {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 80%;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    max-width: 20%;
    max-height: 5%;
}

.hdr_txt {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 60%;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    direction: rtl;
}

.c1_font {
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-family: Times;
    direction: rtl;
}

.line {
    width: 80%;
    height: 10%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #7d97ad;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <header class="container1">
        <figure><img class="logo" src="image.jpg" alt="Alt"></figure>
        <div class="hdr_txt">FULL NAME
            <div class="c1_font">DESIGNATION</div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <hr class="line">
</body>
```

Comment: Don't add `<style>` tag to your css file.

Comment: `<style>` is an **`HTML`** tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<style> </style>` tags from your external CSS file:

Snippet:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.container1 {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  max-width: 20%;
  max-height: 5%;
}

.hdr_txt {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  direction: rtl;
}

.c1_font {
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-family: Times;
  direction: rtl;
}

.line {
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #7d97ad;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Split Check</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="container1">
    <figure><img class="logo" src="image.jpg" alt="Alt"></figure>
    <div class="hdr_txt">FULL NAME
      <div class="c1_font">DESIGNATION</div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <hr class="line">
</body>
```